InternalOAuthError: Failed to fetch user profile with Passport.js LinkedIn Strategy
I'm trying to implement LinkedIn authentication in my Node.js application using Passport.js and the passport-linkedin-oauth2 package. After a successful login redirect, I'm encountering the following error:
InternalOAuthError: failed to fetch user profile
    at Strategy.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jahed\MdShayemurRahman-github\002-thesis\backend\node_modules\passport-linkedin-oauth2\lib\oauth2.js:57:19)
    at passBackControl (C:\Users\jahed\MdShayemurRahman-github\002-thesis\backend\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jahed\MdShayemurRahman-github\002-thesis\backend\node_modules\oauth\lib\oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:526:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1408:12)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)

I've double-checked that my clientID, clientSecret, and callbackURL match exactly with the ones from LinkedIn Developer Platform. I've also ensured the LinkedIn account has granted the necessary permissions.
ScreenShot LinkedIn Developer Platform
Here's the relevant code snippet:
import express from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';
import passport from 'passport';
import session from 'express-session';

import { Strategy as LinkedInStrategy } from 'passport-linkedin-oauth2';


const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(
  session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET, 
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      secure: false, 
    },
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
  new LinkedInStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
      callbackURL: process.env.LINKEDIN_CALLBACK_URL,
      scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'w_member_social', 'email'],
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(
    `<center style="font-size:140%"> <p>LOGIN </p>
      <img style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="window.location='/auth/linkedin'" src="http://bkpandey.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/linkedinlogin.png"/>
      </center>
      `
  );
});

app.get('/auth/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin'));

app.get(
  '/auth/linkedin/callback',
  passport.authenticate('linkedin', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/',
  })
);

// Route to handle successful authentication
app.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
  res.send('You are authenticated with LinkedIn!');
});


export default app;

I've tried restarting my server and testing with a different network, but the issue persists. What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it to successfully fetch the user profile information from LinkedIn?

Since August 2023, LinkedIn has changed its APIs again. And the documentation remains unclear, which creates confusion because it mixes references from old versions with the new one.
Actually, The scopes names for authentication with OpenID collect have changed. Now the authorized scopes are : email, profile and openid according to this. So removing the w_member_social field might be helpful for you.
Also, your /auth/linkedin endpoint should be defined with a state as follows :
app.get('/auth/linkedin', passport.authenticate('linkedin',  { state: 'WHATEVER' }));

The version of passport-linkedin-oauth2 library that supports this change is not yet available as npm package at this time. But there's a way to use it anyway. Check this
And still, the points above will not completely fix the issue. The next step is for you to implement functions following the 3-legged. To start, this is how i would defined your callback enpoint :
app.get('/linkedin/callback', middleware, controller.signupThirdPartyHandler);

When the requests hits your callback endpoints, it comes with a code as a query param that could be used to get the access token from linkedin. And then, the access token could be used to fetch user information within the scope.
export default async function middleware = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    try {

        const code = await req.query.code;
        const accessData = await getAccessToken(code);
        const userInfo = await getUserInfo(accessData.access_token);

        if (!userInfo) {
            // throw ...
        }

        const data: ThirdPartySignupDto = {
            first_name: userInfo.given_name ? userInfo.given_name : '',
            last_name: userInfo.family_name ? userInfo.family_name : '',
            email: userInfo.email ? userInfo.email : null,
            accessToken: accessData.access_token,
            provider: "linkedin"
        }

        req.body = data;
        next();

    } catch (error) {
        // handle error
    }
}

Additionnaly, the following is the implementation of the two methods i used above :
const getAccessToken = async (code: string) => {
        try {
            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                params: {
                    grant_type: 'authorization_code',
                    code: code,
                    client_id: EnvConfig.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_ID,
                    client_secret: EnvConfig.LINKEDIN_CLIENT_SECRET,
                    redirect_uri: EnvConfig.LINKEDIN_CALLBACK_URL,
                }
            }

            const response = await axios.post('https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken', null, config);
            return response.data;

        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error:getAccessToken', error);
            // Handle errors
        }
    };
    const getUserInfo = async (token: String) => {
        try {

            const config = {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            };

            const response = await axios.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo', config);
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error:getUserInfo', error.code);
            // Handle errors
        }
    }

Hopefully it will work !
